# Pandas count different combinations of 2 columns with nan

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe similar to

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, np.nan,2,3, np.nan,4], 'B': [np.nan, 1,np.nan,2, 3, np.nan]})
df
     A    B
0  1.0  NaN
1  NaN  1.0
2  2.0  NaN
3  3.0  2.0
4  NaN  3.0
5  4.0  NaN
```

How do I count the number of occurrences of A is `np.nan` but B not `np.nan`, A not `np.nan` but B is `np.nan`, and A and B both not `np.nan`?

I tried `df.groupby(['A', 'B']).count()` but it doesn't read the rows with `np.nan`.

Comment: 1) What should the output be for your data?

Comment: 2) IOW, you only want to exclude rows where both A and B are NaN?

Comment: ^ yes I don't have that type of row in my dataframe

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using

```
df.isnull().groupby(['A','B']).size()
Out[541]: 
A      B    
False  False    1
       True     3
True   False    2
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 6):

If we are dealing with two columns only, there's a very simple solution that involves assigning simple weights to columns A and B, then summing them.

```
v = df.isna().mul([1, 2]).sum(1).value_counts() 
v.index = v.index.map({2: 'only B', 1: 'only A', 0: 'neither'})    
v

only B     3
only A     2
neither    1
dtype: int64
```

---

Another alternative with `pivot_table` and `stack` can be achieved by,

```
df.isna().pivot_table(index='A', columns='B', aggfunc='size').stack()

A      B    
False  False    1.0
       True     3.0
True   False    2.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`DataFrame.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) with [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) for count Trues values:

```
df1 = df.isna()
df2 = pd.crosstab(df1.A, df1.B)
print (df2)
B      False  True 
A                  
False      1      3
True       2      0
```

For scalar:

```
print (df2.loc[False, False])
1
```

---

```
df2 = pd.crosstab(df1.A, df1.B).add_prefix('B_').rename(lambda x: 'A_' + str(x))
print (df2)
B        B_False  B_True
A                       
A_False        1       3
A_True         2       0
```

Then for scalar use indexing:

```
print (df2.loc['A_False', 'B_False'])
1
```

Another solution is use [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) by columns names with [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) and [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, np.nan,2,3, np.nan,4, np.nan], 
                   'B': [np.nan, 1,np.nan,2, 3, np.nan, np.nan]})

s = df.isna().dot(df.columns).replace({'':'no match'}).value_counts()
print (s)

B           3
A           2
no match    1
AB          1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, np.nan,2,3, np.nan,4], 'B': [np.nan, 1,np.nan,2, 3, np.nan]})

count1 = len(df[(~df['A'].isnull()) & (df['B'].isnull())])
count2 = len(df[(~df['A'].isnull()) & (~df['B'].isnull())])
count3 = len(df[(df['A'].isnull()) & (~df['B'].isnull())])

print(count1, count2, count3)
```

Output:

```
3 1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

To get rows where either A or B is null, we can do:

```
bool_df = df.isnull()
df[bool_df['A'] ^ bool_df['B']].shape[0]
```

To get rows where both are null values:

```
df[bool_df['A'] & bool_df['B']].shape[0]
```